# Looping over csv files in a Python directory

Tags: python, loops, path, directory

I'm running this script to loop over a directory of CSV files to run cross validation on.

```
for filename in os.listdir("/Users/name/PycharmProjects/Project/Data/Nod"):
    k_fold(filename)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path_of_cross_validation_file", line 28, in <module>
k_fold(filename)
File "/path_of_cross_validation_file", line 7, in k_fold
data = open(myfile).readlines()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file_name.csv'
```

How do I iterate through all these files to split the data into training and testing files?

For reference, a file in `Nod` could look like this:

```
x,y,z
-1.3518261999999999,0.19841946999999999,0.058807577999999999
-1.5427636999999998,0.54079030000000006,-0.15981296
-1.4453497,0.04129998,0.046387657999999998
-1.4743793000000001,-0.064793080000000003,0.18315643000000001
```

Comment: You need to include the path to the directory when attempting to open the file in it.

Comment: I'm confused by the difference between folder and directory here. I set my path to the folder that contains all `.csv` files.

Comment: What's confusing? Until *you wrote that comment* they were consistently described by both of us as directories. Folder is generally a synonym.

Comment: Well, I did do what you said I need to do. I added the details in the question

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed to use the glob module.

Here's the solution:

```
for filename in glob.iglob('Path_to_directory/*.csv'):
    k_fold(filename)
```